# Infinite loop on v-for loop when trying to execute function inside

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

It's very simple thing and I know is a noob mistake, but I'm blocked in this issue.
I want to know how to execute function inside template, without event firing or render data.
In this example I wan't to increment numberOfItems, that are the number of loops that this component execute. Inside v-for I add {{ aFunctionCall() }}, but this is executing in a infinite loop because component is trying to re-render recursively.

This is the warning that give me Vue in console.log:

> Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

How can I execute a function in each loop without re-rendering recursively?

This is the component code.

```
<template>
        <div class="repeater-wrapper">
            <div 
                class="repeater-item"
                v-for="(input, index) in min"
            >
            {{ addNumberOfItems() }}
            {{ sayHello() }}
            </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        min: {
            type: Number
        },
        max: {
            type: Number,
            default: 10
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            status: 'normal',
            validate: true,
            numberOfItems: 0
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addNumberOfItems(number=1){
            console.log( 'It is fired', this.numberOfItems )
            this.numberOfItems += number;
            return this.numberOfItems;
        },
        sayHello(){
            //Any other function I want to execute on each loop
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Parent Component that call this component is:

```
<Repeater :min="2"/>
```

Comment: You are looping v-for with the `min` property, but you didn't share the code where you are setting the value to it. Share that piece of code to dig deeper.

Comment: Sorry, it's a simple number.

This is the call of component in parent component:
<Repeater :min="2">

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can fix it this way :

```
data() {
  return {
    status: 'normal',
    validate: true,
    tmp: 0,
    numberOfItems: 0,
  };
},
methods: {
  addNumberOfItems(number = 1) {
    console.log('It is fired', this.numberOfItems);
    this.numberOfItems += number;
    this.tmp = this.numberOfItems;

    return this.tmp;
  }
```

In the first addNumberOfItems method you provided, you are assigning the result of this.numberOfItems + number to the tmp data property, which means that the numberOfItems property is not being directly modified. This could be why you are not experiencing an infinite loop when using this method in your template.

In the second addNumberOfItems method, you are directly modifying the numberOfItems property using the += operator, which could potentially trigger a re-render of the template if the numberOfItems property is being used in a way that causes the template to depend on it.

For example, if you have a computed property that depends on numberOfItems, or if you are using numberOfItems in a v-for loop or in a computed class, then modifying the numberOfItems property directly could cause the template to re-render, leading to an infinite loop if not handled properly.

I recommend changing the variable name :)

Hope it works for you !